# Add php database to java script file

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on a project of web calendar. I want to add my php database file to the java script file. When I click on the save button of calendar, the entries showed in calendar, but I m unable to add PHP file to save button. So when I click on save button, the entry should go to the database(php file).

code goes here:-

```
buttons: 
        {
           save : function() 
           {
              calEvent.id = id;
              id++;
              calEvent.start = new Date(startField.val());
              calEvent.end = new Date(endField.val());
              calEvent.title = titleField.val();
              calEvent.body = bodyField.val();

              $calendar.weekCalendar("removeUnsavedEvents");
              $calendar.weekCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
              $dialogContent.dialog("close");

           },
           cancel : function() {
              $dialogContent.dialog("close");
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "PHP database", and you cannot add PHP to your JavaScript file.

Your save button needs to send data to a PHP via page via HTTP, either by regular post-back or AJAX. The page will reside and execute on your server, while the JavaScript calendar executes in the client's browser. That PHP page can then talk to a database server to store/retrieve data for you.

Your server must:

- be set up to execute PHP files correctly
- have a running database server (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc)
- have a database and table in which to hold your data

Comment: i am using Mysql as database server via wamp. the connectivity is through php file. so i want to link my js file with php file to connect with the database. on clicking to the save button, it redirects to php file and then to the database server. how can i do it?

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on using PHP to talk to MySQL. We're not going to write the code for you. If you have a specific question, you can come back to Stack Overflow and ask it.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that a database is at the server end (sometime the web server).

It could by Sybase, MySql, SQLite, ...

Nothing to do with the server.

Javascript on the browser can and sometimes is turned off. It just makes it easier and more interactive to use the web pages.

So why should summat go to a *php file*? This makes no sense along with *php base*. Please have a little reflection on the various technologies involved.

Comment: i am using Mysql as database server via wamp. the connectivity is through php file. so i want to link my js file with php file to connect with the database. on clicking to the save button, it redirects to php file and then to the database server. how can i do it?